# Can we create swig for C Python Extension for PIC Microcontroller?

Tags: c, python-3.x, swig

I have C files and .h files in MPLab Project which are getting compiled using XC32 compiler.XC32 internally has GCC compiler only.
So how i can create swig wrapper for it?

Created sample LED Blinking Project and compiled it using XC32 compiler. But not getting now how i can use swig here.

Comment: Did you try anything? Swig generates C or C++ source. Did you make any attempt and try to compile it?

Comment: I have tried with Swig generator for C given in Examples folder.I could import the module in Python.Now my next target is to do this with PIC controller code, so i just created main.c which has LED Blink code. Now i am not getting how swig can be used here, as main.c has while loop as below:#include <xc.h>

int main()
{

    TRISA =0x00;
    ANSELA =0X00;
    while(1)
    {
        LATAINV = 0xFF;
        for(int i=0; i<1000;i++)
            for(int j=0; j<50;j++);
    }
    

}